# Graphite dashboard isn't showing datapoints older than one week

Tags: graphite

I'm using [docker-grafana-graphite](https://github.com/kamon-io/docker-grafana-graphite) to collecting datapoints. When I request to get datapoints for last 30 days or older than one week it shows datapoints only for last week (last 7 days).

When I request to summarized datapoints for last 30 days:

```
/render/?target=summarize(stats.counters.test-server.comp.counter.sms_messages.count,'1hour','sum')&from=-30d&until=now&format=json
```

I'm getting result for only last 7 days and result looks like this:

```
{
  target: "summarize(stats.counters.test-server.comp.counter.sms_messages.count, "1hour", "sum")",
  datapoints: [
    [10, 1516363200],
    [5, 1516366800],
    ...
    [2, 1516964400],
    [0, 1516968000]
  ]
}
```

It works if I request for a small range less than one week, but I would like to get all datapoints for last 30 days. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: It might be a maxDatapoints issue, try using 

```/render/?target=summarize(stats.counters.test-server.comp.counter.sms_messages.count,'1hour','sum')&from=-30d&until=now&format=json
&maxDataPoints=720```

Comment: I've tried with `maxDataPoints` but still showing same result

Comment: Can you check that you have retention policy of more than 7 days